# How do I position my React component beneath the navbar (so that the navbar doesn't overlap it)?

Tags: css, reactjs, components, navbar

I'm trying to build a React 16.13.0 application, which is laid out in a fairly simple way -- the nav bar on top and the component below ...

```
  return (<Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Flash />
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
        <div className="container">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to={"/add"}>Chicommons</Link>
          <NavBar />
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div className="auth-wrapper">
        <div className="auth-inner">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Add} />
            <Route path="/add" component={Add} />
            <Route path="/search" component={Search} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
```

I have created the following styles for the different sections ...

```
.navbar-light {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 14px 80px rgba(34, 35, 58, 0.2);
}

.auth-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
}

.auth-inner {
  width: 450px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 14px 80px rgba(34, 35, 58, 0.2);
  padding: 40px 55px 45px 55px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: all .3s;
}
```

However, the nav bar is overlapping the component.  Demo can be seen here -- http://prod.chicommons.coop, or this screen shot

[image]

How do I adjust things so that my component appears below the nav bar and is completely visible (it's fine if you have to scroll)?

Comment: From my own experience, you should avoid using sticky, fixed-top... Use a css grid instead and you will never have overlaps anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change **position** property from file  **scss/utilities/_position.scss**. It can be either **position:sticky** or **position:initial** or anything except absolute or relative.

eg:-

```
.fixed-bottom, .fixed-top {
position: initial;
right: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1030;
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the default file installed with bootstrap, i.e. ./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/_position.scss ?  Is there a way to do the edits you're suggesting without altering installed modules that I didn't write?

Comment: Yes,  you can do it without editing bootstrap. Add  any of these to your css file.  ```nav.navbar {
position: static;
}```  or ```nav.navbar {
position: inherit;
}``` or ```nav.navbar {
position: initial;
}```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have `position: fixed` on your Navbar, your `auth-wrapper` DOM element starts from the top

There are now multiple solutions to these depending on how you want your Navbar to behave

Since you would like a Navbar sticking to the top and not scrolling with the rest of the DOM, you could make it `position: sticky` instead of `position: fixed` and add a small padding to your `authWrapper` to give enough space on top

Since you are using `bootstrap` class `fixed-top` for now. I suggest you replace it with your own custom class

```
 <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-fixed-top">
    <div className="container">
      <Link className="navbar-brand" to={"/add"}>Chicommons</Link>
      <NavBar />
    </div>
  </nav>


.navbar.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.auth-wrapper {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
}
```

the above solution will however lead to your Navbar looking out of place when you scroll to the end of the page

A better solution here would be to use `position: fixed` instead of `position: sticky` and add a `padding-top` or `top`  css to `auth-wrapper`

```
.navbar.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.auth-wrapper {
  padding-top: 6rem; // enough space towards the top to be not overlapped by navbar
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: I notice you're hard-coding "6rem."  Isn't there some way to instruct the style to always position the content beneath the nav component without having to know the exact size of the nav?  If CSS has that capability, that's the way I'd like to go.

Comment: @Dave That is what the first solution offers. What it comes with a small drawback.

Answer (score 0):

you have given fixed-top class to your nav. it will cause it to overlap everything (like it has no height for the other elements). Remove the fixed-top class and then if you want, add it to your navbar after scrolling so it would stick to the top when the user scrolls down. (You can also give a little margin-top to your form so it would not stick to your nav to become more beautiful.)

Answer (score 0):

use `position: sticky;` instead of `position: fixed;` on this class `.fixed-bottom, .fixed-top`